# How can i configure Django-Cors-Header properly

Tags: python, django, django-cors-headers, drf-yasg, fly

I deployed my django app on fly.io. When accessing api endpoints with swagger, I get this error in the console; "

```
The page at 'https://bookinventory.fly.dev/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://bookinventory.fly.dev/api/view/1'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Cors has been installed with settings from the docs.

I have set;

```
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
```

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    'https://bookinventory.fly.dev', 'http://bookinventory.fly.dev']
```

And the middleware and installed apps has all ben configured for cors